# Get list of nearby antennas

Tags: android

How can I get the list of nearby antennas and the received signals strength in Android ( Using java or any other technology, I just want to know if it's possible ) ?

UPDATE

I'm interested in phone antennas like 2G 3G 4G.

Comment: What antennas? WiFi, Bluetooth, phone masts?  This needs to be made clearer. It would require the receiving device to measure the signal strength and return the strength to the originator which would require the receiver running an application. WiFi and Bluetooth is fairly simple to do if you have a second device but phone signals is a lot less straightforward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot obtain the list of nearby antennas programmatically.

Though you can easily obtain the `Telephony Signal Strengths` using the `SignalStrength` API here [SignalStrength](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SignalStrength.html) and for `Wifi` Signal Strength you can refer to the `WifiManager` API enlisted here [WifiManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html).

Comment: Consider up-voting and accepting my answer if you found it helpful.